# pasted variable name not recognized in loop

Tags: r, loops, paste

sorry for the ugly code, but I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong

```
for (i in 1:1) 
    tab_sector[1:48,i] <- 
        tapply(get(paste("employee",1997-1+i, "[birth<=(1997-1+i)]",sep="")),
               ordered(sic2digit[birth<=(1997-1+i)],levels=tab_sector_list))

# Error in get(paste("employee", 1997 - 1 + i, 
# "[birth<=(1997-1+i))]",  : object 'employee97[birth<=(1997-1+i)]' not found
```

but the variable is there:

```
head(employee97[birth<=(1997-1+i)])
# [1] 1 2 2 1 3 4
```

a simpler version where "employee" is not conditioned by "birth" works

Comment: Could be nothing, but shouldn't `paste("employee",1997-1+i, "[birth<=(1997-1+i)]",sep="")`  give you `employee1997[birth<=(1997-1+i)]`  rather than `employee97[...` ?  either the code snippet or the error reported by R doesn't match!

Comment: sorry, my mistake, in an effort to make it simpler I modified the earlier (even uglier) index: "employee",(1997-1901+i) -- apologies for adding a further layer of confusion

Answer (score 2):

You can't `get` an indexed element, e.g. `get("x[i]")` fails: you need `get("x")[i]`.

Your code is almost too messy too see what's going on, but this is an attempt at a translation:

```
   for (i in 1:1){
        ind <- 1997-1+i
        v1 <- get(paste0("employee",ind))
        tab_sector[1:48,i] <- tapply(v1[birth<=ind],
             ordered(sic2digit[birth<=ind],levels=tab_sector_list))
    }
```

Comment: get ("x")[i] was indeed the tip I needed -- thanks with apologies for messy code

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you told us what you are trying to accomplish.

In your code the `get` function is looking for a variable whose name is "'employee97[birth<=(1997-1+i)]", the code that works is finding a variable whose name is "employee1997" then subsetting it, those are very different.  The `get` function does not do subsetting.

Part of what you are trying to do is FAQ 7.21, the most important part of which is the end where it suggests storing your data in lists to make accessing easier.